# comparing s.at(i) to a character?

Tags: c++, string, templates

**I'm getting an error that C++ forbids comparison of pointer with character**

some sort of -fpermissive error wherever i compare s.at(i) with anything.

```
 string s;
        cout<<"Enter the expression";
        getline(cin,s);
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
          {
              if(s.at(i)=="("||s.at(i)=="["||s.at(i)=="{")
                push(s.at(i));
          }
          for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
          {
              if(s.at(i)=="]"||s.at(i)==")"||s.at(i)=="}")
              {
                  x=pop();
                  if (s.at(i)==x)
                    continue;
                  else
                  {enter code here
                      cout<<"\nInvalid expression";
                      return 0;
                  }
              }
          }
```

Comment: "I'm getting an error" is too broad. Please paste the concrete error message here.

Comment: So, your loop ensures that the value of `i` is greater than or equal to zero, and less than the length of the string, but you also use `std::string::at()` to check that the index is in bounds, in case the compiler gets confused? `s[i]` works just fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `s.at(i)=="("`.

The *literal* `"("` is actually a `const char[2]` type (one element for the `(`, the other for a NUL-terimator), which *decays* into a `const char*` pointer under certain instances, such as this case when using `==`.

`s.at(i)` returns a single `char` type, which is being compared to a `const char*` pointer. Your helpful compiler is warning you of this error.

The solution is simple: use `'('` instead, which is a single `char` literal.  You can compare a `char` to a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You are encasing characters in double quotes `")"` which makes them strings, or `char *`'s.  They should be in single quotes, like `')'` so they become `char`'s.